# Can't open database file generated by Entity Framework on other machine

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework code first in my application. If I create database on first machine and afrer that pust to git my project with database(.mdf and .ldf files)and try clone this project in other machine, but when I run this project it can't open database(permissions errors).

Do it posible create in Entity fraimwork database with some user or create database without autification permisions?

Couul you give some example of connection string or DbContextConfiguration?

Here is my exception:

> Cannot create file
>   'D:\nullam\Nullam.WebUI\App_Data\Nullam.DataLayer.NullamDbContext.mdf'
>   because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and
>   retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed
>   could not be created. Check related errors.

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Nullam.DataLayer;
namespace Nullam.WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NullamDbContext>());
        }
    }
}
```

**NullamDbContext.cs**

```
using Nullam.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Nullam.DataLayer
{
    public class NullamDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public NullamDbContext() : base("NullamDb")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SocialEvent> SocialEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Nullam.DataLayer.Migrations
{
    class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<NullamDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(NullamDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NullamDb"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Nullam.DataLayer.NullamDbContext.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what is the error ? can you share your code also for the same items which you mentioned ?

Comment: @Sampath I added code to my question. Also I want notice that I don't changed model and database must not drop. I tried connect to database via connection exploner ant it not allow me. Exception: Cannot open database "Nullam.DataLayer.NullamDbContext" requested by the login. The login failed. I used windows authentification. If you need more code I will edit my question again. Thanks.

Comment: Try to start Visual Studio with ADMIN rights

Comment: Similar to @swissben answer, in the new machine, try start the IIS application pool with Administrator and add the impersonated user to Administrators Group.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking in the database when it would be created when you launch the application.

Delete the database from GIT and the machine you have downloaded it to and re-run the application, it will create the database in the location specified in the web.config.

Comment: If I wnt that all database data was in another pc, how I can provide it?